# Monotone chain change data structure to doubly linked list

Tags: computational-geometry

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    while (k >= 2 && cross(H[k-2], H[k-1], P[i]) <= 0) k--;
    H[k++] = P[i];

for (size_t i = n-1, t = k+1; i > 0; --i) {
    while (k >= t && cross(H[k-2], H[k-1], P[i-1]) <= 0) k--;
    H[k++] = P[i-1];
```

I found the code for it on wikipedia but for some reasons I prefer to use doubly linked list as data structure 
 The problem is in this first condition for while loop while(k>=2&&...) and while(k>=t && ...)
How can I rewrite these while loops on linked list

Comment: Show us your attempts.

Comment: I think i have solution but i had to add node counter to my linked list and I am not content of this solution Do you remember Pascal ? Segmentantion fault happened
 while I tried to sort linked list using BST inside procedure which finds convex hull

Comment: Sorry, I am not going to troubleshoot your Pascal code (though I loved Pascal). Try to unit-test your linked list management routines, then the sort.

Comment: Then why you wanted to get the code I think i know how to correct sorting routine

Answer (score 0):

```
unit DoublyLinkedList;
interface
const NULL = NIL;
type TPoint = record
                x,y:longint;
              end;
     PLink = ^TLink;
     TLink = record
                point:TPoint;
                next:PLink;
                prev:PLink;
             end;
    TList = record
                first:PLink;
                last:PLink;
            end;
    TFunc = function(A,B:TPoint):integer;

procedure ListInit(var L:TList);
function  ListFind(L:TList;key:TPoint):PLink;
function  ListIsEmpty(L:TList):boolean;
procedure ListInsertFirst(var L:TList;dd:TPoint);
procedure ListInsertLast(var L:TList;dd:TPoint);
procedure ListDeleteFirst(var L:TList);
procedure ListDeleteLast(var L:TList);
procedure ListInsert(var L:TList;dd:TPoint);
function ListInsertAfter(var L:TList;key,dd:TPoint):boolean;
procedure ListDeleteKey(var L:TList;key:TPoint);
procedure ListDisplayForward(L:TList);
procedure ListDisplayBackward(L:TList);
procedure BSTsort(var L:TList);

implementation
function equals(p1,p2:TPoint):boolean;
begin
  equals:=(p1.x = p2.x) and (p1.y = p2.y);
end;
function compare(A,B:TPoint):integer;
var t:integer;
begin
  t := 1;
  if(A.x < B.x)or((A.x = B.x)and(A.y < B.y))then
        t := -1;
  if(A.x = B.x)and(A.y = B.y)then
        t := 0;
  compare := t;
end;
procedure BSTinsert(var root:PLink;x:PLink);
begin
        if root = NULL then
        begin
        root := x;
                x^.prev := NULL;
                x^.next := NULL;
        end
    else if compare(root^.point,x^.point) = 0 then
        BSTinsert(root^.prev,x)
    else if compare(root^.point,x^.point) < 0 then
                BSTinsert(root^.next,x)
    else
                BSTinsert(root^.prev,x);
end;
procedure BSTtoDLL(root:PLink;var L:TList);
begin
  if root <> NULL then
  begin
    BSTtoDLL(root^.prev,L);
    if ListIsEmpty(L) then
        L.first := root
    else
        L.last^.next := root;
    root^.prev := L.last;
    L.last := root;
    BSTtoDLL(root^.next,L);
  end;
end;
procedure BSTsort(var L:TList);
var root,temp:PLink;
begin
  root := NULL; (*This instruction was missing in the code *)
  while not ListIsEmpty(L)do
  begin
    temp := L.first;
    if L.first^.next = NULL then
        L.last := NULL
    else
        L.first^.next^.prev := NULL;
    L.first := L.first^.next;
        BSTinsert(root,temp);
  end;
  BSTtoDLL(root,L);
end;
procedure ListInit(var L:TList);
begin
  L.first := NULL;
  L.last := NULL;
end;
function  ListFind(L:TList;key:TPoint):PLink;
var p:PLink;
begin
  p := L.first;
  while(p <> NULL)and(not equals(key,p^.point))do
    p := p^.next;
  ListFind := p;
end;
function  ListIsEmpty(L:TList):boolean;
begin
  ListIsEmpty := L.first = NULL;
end;
procedure ListInsertFirst(var L:TList;dd:TPoint);
var newLink:PLink;
begin
  new(newLink);
  newLink^.point.x := dd.x;
  newLink^.point.y := dd.y;
  newLink^.next := NULL;
  newLink^.prev := NULL;
  if ListIsEmpty(L) then
     L.last := newLink
  else
    L.first^.prev := newLink;
  newLink^.next := L.first;
  L.first := newLink;   
end;
procedure ListInsertLast(var L:TList;dd:TPoint);
var newLink:PLink;
begin
  new(newLink);
  newLink^.point.x := dd.x;
  newLink^.point.y := dd.y;
  newLink^.next := NULL;
  newLink^.prev := NULL;
  if ListIsEmpty(L) then
     L.first := newLink
  else
  begin
    L.last^.next := newLink;
    newLink^.prev := L.last;
  end;
  L.last := newLink;
end;
procedure ListDeleteFirst(var L:TList);
var temp:PLink;
begin
  if not ListIsEmpty(L) then
  begin
    temp := L.first;
    if L.first^.next = NULL then
        L.last := NULL
    else
        L.first^.next^.prev := NULL;
    L.first := L.first^.next;
    dispose(temp);
  end;  
end;
procedure ListDeleteLast(var L:TList);
var temp:PLink;
begin
  if not ListIsEmpty(L) then
  begin
    temp := L.last;
    if L.first^.next = NULL then
        L.first := NULL
    else
        L.last^.prev^.next := NULL;
    L.last := L.last^.prev;
    dispose(temp);
  end;
end;
procedure ListInsert(var L:TList;dd:TPoint);
var newLink,current:PLink;
begin
  new(newLink);
  newLink^.point.x := dd.x;
  newLink^.point.y := dd.y;
  newLink^.next := NULL;
  newLink^.prev := NULL;
  current := L.first;
  while(current <> NULL)and(compare(newLink^.point,current^.point) > 0)do
     current := current^.next;
  if current = NULL then
  begin
    if ListIsEmpty(L)then
        L.first := newLink
    else
    begin
        L.last^.next := newLink;
        newLink^.prev := L.last;
    end;
    L.last := newLink;
  end
  else if current^.prev = NULL then
  begin
    L.first := newLink;
    newLink^.next := current;
    current^.prev := newLink;
    newLink^.prev := NULL;
    current := newLink;
  end
  else
  begin
     current^.prev^.next := newLink;
     newLink^.next := current;
     newLink^.prev := current^.prev;
     current^.prev := newLink;
  end;
end;
function ListInsertAfter(var L:TList;key,dd:TPoint):boolean;
var newLink,current:PLink;
    found:boolean;
begin
  current := ListFind(L,key);
  found := current <> NULL;
  if found then
  begin
    new(newLink);
    newLink^.point.x := dd.x;
    newLink^.point.y := dd.y;
    newLink^.next := NULL;
    newLink^.prev := NULL;
    if current^.next = NULL then
    begin
      newLink^.next := NULL;
      L.last := newLink;    
    end
    else
    begin
      newLink^.next := current^.next;
      current^.next^.prev := newLink;   
    end;
    newLink^.prev := current;
    current^.next := newLink;
  end;
  ListInsertAfter:= found;  
end;
procedure ListDeleteKey(var L:TList;key:TPoint);
var current:PLink;
begin
  current := ListFind(L,key);
  if current <> NULL then
  begin
    if current^.prev = NULL then
        L.first := current^.next
    else
        current^.prev^.next := current^.next;
    if current^.next = NULL then
        L.last := current^.prev
    else
        current^.next^.prev := current^.prev;
    dispose(current);
  end;
end;
procedure ListDisplayForward(L:TList);
var current :PLink;
begin
  write('List (first-->last): ');
  current := L.first;
  while current <> NIL do
  begin
    write('(',current^.point.x,',',current^.point.y,') -> ');
    current := current^.next;
  end;
  writeln('NULL');  
end;
procedure ListDisplayBackward(L:TList);
var current :PLink;
begin
  write('List (last-->first): ');
  current := L.last;
  while current <> NIL do
  begin
    write('(',current^.point.x,',',current^.point.y,') -> ');
    current := current^.prev;
  end;
  writeln('NULL');  
end;

begin

end.


program MonotoneChain;

uses crt,doublylinkedlist;

function equals(a,b:TPoint):boolean;
begin
  equals := (a.x = b.x) and (a.y = b.y)
end;

function vect(a1,a2,b1,b2:TPoint):longint;
begin
  vect := (a2.x - a1.x) * (b2.y - b1.y) - (b2.x - b1.x) * (a2.y - a1.y)
end;

function dist2(a1,a2:TPoint):longint;
begin
  dist2 := sqr(a2.x - a1.x) + sqr(a2.y-a1.y)
end;

procedure Solve(var A,B:TList);
var k,t:longint;
    pt:PLink;
begin
  ListInit(B);
  if not ListIsEmpty(A)then
  begin
    k := 0;
    pt := A.first;
    while pt <> NULL do
    begin
      while(k >= 2)and(vect(B.last^.prev^.point,B.last^.point,B.last^.prev^.point,pt^.point) <= 0)do
      begin
        ListDeleteLast(B);
        k := k - 1;
      end;
      ListInsertLast(B,pt^.point);
      k := k + 1;
      pt := pt^.next;
    end;
    t := k + 1;
    pt := A.last;
    while pt <> NULL do
    begin
      while(k >= t)and(vect(B.last^.prev^.point,B.last^.point,B.last^.prev^.point,pt^.point) <= 0)do
      begin
        ListDeleteLast(B);
        k := k - 1;
      end;
      ListInsertLast(B,pt^.point);
      k := k + 1;
      pt := pt^.prev;
    end;
    ListDeleteLast(B);
  end;
end;



procedure main;
var A,B:TList;
    input:text;
    p:TPoint;
    path:string;
begin
  ListInit(A);
  writeln('Podaj sciezke do pliku z danymi do wczytania');
  readln(path);
  path := 'F:\fpc\3.0.4\bin\i386-win32\monotonechain\' + path;
  assign(input,path);
  {$I-}
  reset(input);
  {$I+}
  if IOResult <> 0 then
     writeln('Pliku nie udalo sie wczytac')
  else
  begin
  while not eof(input) do
  begin
    while not eoln(input) do
    begin
      read(input,p.x,p.y);
      ListInsertLast(A,p);
    end;
    readln(input);
    writeln('List A');
    ListDisplayForward(A);
    ListDisplayBackward(A);
    BSTsort(A);
    Solve(A,B);
    writeln('List A');
    ListDisplayForward(A);
    ListDisplayBackward(A);
    writeln('List B');
    ListDisplayForward(B);
    ListDisplayBackward(B);
    while not ListIsEmpty(A) do
       ListDeleteFirst(A);
   while not ListIsEmpty(B) do
       ListDeleteFirst(B);
  end;
  close(input);
  end;
  readkey;
end;


BEGIN
  main;
END.
```

Here is the code

Segmentation fault appears while I try to sort
the list using BST 
Probably when I try to insert the node removed from head of the list to the BST 
Segmentation fault appears only when I call it from procedure which finds the convex hull
When I call it from main block of code everything seem to be ok
One of the casese of segmentetion fault is dereferencing null pointer
but i dont know is this segmentation fault caused by dereferencing null pointer
It is strange for me that BSTsort called in main block of code works ok
but BSTsort called in Solve procedure causes segmentation fault

I think i know how to correct this sorting procedure 
but I would like to know why segmentation fault occured and why only
in Solve procedure